# Checking if the value of a string is true - python

Tags: python, string, list, loops, if-statement

I am trying to see if a string is true or false but im stuck... In the following code I have made a list of statements that I want to evaluate, I have put them in strings because the variables need to be declared after the list is .(Reason is that the list of statements to be evaluated are being passed as a parameter to a function, in this function the variables are declared) I want to run through all of the items in the list and if it is a true statement then do something... Here is my code: (There is no output generated)

```
a = ['b > c', 'b = c', 'b < c']

b = 5
c = 3

for item in a:
    if exec(item):
       print(item)
```

Comment: You could use `eval(item)` but it's not generally recommended

Comment: *variables need to be declared after the list is* <-- Why? That seems like an arbitrary (and mistaken) implementation. Perhaps there are valid reasons for this, but you could clarify if that is the case...

Comment: Ok I have now done so ^^ @DavidZemens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`exec` is a function in python3.x<sup>1</sup> that returns `None` so you'll always have a falsy result.  You probably want `eval`.

Also be careful here.  Do not use this unless you completely trust the input strings as it will allow execution of arbitrary code otherwise.

---

Note that this is a *very* strange code design and there is *probably* a better way to accomplish what you want...  For example:

*Why* do you want to define the strings *before* the variables are defined?  Coupling strings to names in your code in this way is likely to lead to a painful code maintenance experience.

<sup><sup>1</sup>In python2.x, this would fail with a `SyntaxError` since `exec` was a *statement* prior to python3.x</sup>

---

Having tried to understand your use-case a little more, I would propose that you create an API where you pass functions.

```
def f1(a, b, **kwargs):
    return a > b

def f2(a, b, **kwargs):
    return a == b

def f3(a, c, **kwargs):
    return a <= c

funcs = [f1, f2, f3]
```

Now you can define a function that will pass the parameters.  You'll need to define *which* parameters it intends to pass -- but it will always pass them all:

```
def func_caller(funcs):
    param_map = {
        'a': get_a_somehow(),
        'b': get_b_somehow(),
        'c': get_c_somehow(),
        ...
    }
    for func in funcs:
        if func(**param_map):
            print("Hello World!")
```

There are other way to make the "contract" between `func_caller` and the functions that it is calling even more binding (e.g. pass the params as a more structured object like a `namedtuple`).

```
from collections import namedtuple
FuncCallerParams = namedtuple('FuncCallerParams', 'a,b,c')

def f1(func_caller_params):
   return func_caller_params.a > func_caller_params.b
...

funcs = [f1, f2, ...]

def func_caller(funcs):
    a = ...
    b = ...
    c = ...
    fcp = FuncCallerParams(a, b, c)
    for func in funcs:
        if func(fcp):
           ...
```

Comment: the reason i'm doing it like so is that I want to list 'a' to be passed as a parameter to a function. In this function the variables are declared. Any suggestions? @mgilson

Comment: @N.Chalifour -- I'm not sure that I'm understanding ... wouldn't this require that the creator of the list `a` know the intimate implementation details of the function (e.g. the variable names used inside it?)  That seems like a really poor way to separate concerns.  What do the variables `b`, and `c` represent?  Where do their values come from?

Comment: In the actual code, `b` and `c` are actually `pb` and `peg` (there are alos others) which are statistics for a company... I need to check if the value of that statistic is for example below 1 for each company @mgilson